# Hexo: How to create a page hierachy

Tags: static-site, hexo

I want to create a page hierachy with the static site generator "Hexo"

It tried the following to create a page inside a folder:

```
hexo new page apps/counter
```

But it creates a folder `apps-counter` with the index file in it. So the page hierachy seem to be flat.

When I try "apps\counter" (as this is windows)  it returns with an "unknown escape sequence error".

Also when I like to have a hierachical page menu, and it is not clear to me how to define it.

Comment: did my answer below help?

Answer (score 3):

For pages, you create hierarchy by changing the permalink. Add the following to the top of your .md file if its a page:

```
permalink: some/hierarchy/mypage
```

Also, in hexo you can define categories. These will also provide hierarchy, but only for posts. Just add the following to the top of your .md file:

```
   categories:
     - some
     - hierarchy
```

This will create the hierarchy `some -> hierarchy`